# Many-to-many relationships in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq, join, group-by

I'm getting data from 2 tables, `Regions` and `Subregions`. A `Region` can have many `Subregions`, linked by `RegionID`.

I want to return all the `Regions` from the database and their related `Subregions`.

I've done this so far:

```
var RegionDet = (from s in context.Region
                 join b in context.SubRegion on s.RegionID equals b.RegionID
                 group b by s.RegionName into g
                 select new RegionsMV
                        {
                            RegionName = g.Key,
                            SubRegions = g.ToList()
                        }).ToList();
```

This works fine, apart from it will only return `Regions` that have `Subregions` associated. If a `Region` has no `Subregion`, it won't be returned. I've tried different ways, but can't get it working as it should

Comment: I don't think subregions can belong to more than 1 region, so this is not many-to-many. The type of join confirms that. Also, why don't you use a navigation property? When properly designed, an EF class model hardly ever needs joins in LINQ queries. A navigation property `region.SubRegions` would be translated to an outer join automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different options for this. Off the cuff, I can think of these:

a. Extend the manual join from the approach in the OP

```
from s in context.Region
join b in context.SubRegion on s.RegionID equals b.RegionID into bg
from b in bg.DefaultIfEmpty()
group b by s.RegionName into g
select new RegionsMV
{
    RegionName = g.Key,
    SubRegions = g.ToList()
}
```

b. Leverage the Entity mapping

```
public class Region 
{
    public int RegionID { get; set; }
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SubRegion> SubRegions { get; set; }
}
```

Then your LINQ query would be:

```
from s in context.Region.Include(r => r.SubRegions)
select new RegionsMV
{
    RegionName = s.RegionName,
    SubRegions = s.SubRegions
}
```

Or this is equivalent:

```
context.Region.Include(r => r.SubRegions)
.Select(s => new RegionsMV()
{
    RegionName = s.RegionName,
    SubRegions = s.SubRegions
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to fetch all the Regions and the SubRegions associated to those Regions.

```
List<Region> regions = context.Region.Include(r => r.SubRegions).ToList();
```

`regions` will contain all Regions. Each Region in the list will contain its SubRegions.

Comment: Although this worked and does what I wanted, I marked the below comment as the answer as it tweaked my code and I could understand where I was going wrong. Thanks